# MVC: JavaScripts no longer working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, view

For some reason my scripts in my view stopped working. They were working before - unfortunately I don't remember at what point they stopped working, so I cannot really reproduce the point where it broke. However, I can tell for sure that I have not changed the script at all. Here's my view:

```
@using errandomWeb.Models
@model errandomWeb.Models.errands
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Get It Done For You";
}
<div id="postErrandContainer" class="manageContainer">
    <div id="postErrandHeaderSection" class="manageHeaderSection">
        <h1 id="postErrandHeaderTitle" class="manageHeaderTitle">
            @ViewBag.Title
        </h1>
    </div>
    <section id="postErrand" class="manageForm">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("PostErrandToDB", "errandom", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "postErrandForm", @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<!-- user activity tracking section -->
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LatitudePosted, new { @id = "postErrandLatitudePosted", @class = "userActivity" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LongitudePosted, new { @id = "postErrandLongitudePosted", @class = "userActivity" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LocationPosted, new { @id = "postErrandLocationPosted", @class = "userActivity" })
<!-- autopopulate errand values with current location -->
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function defaultPostValues() {
                    if (!navigator.geolocation) return;
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (userCoordinates) {
                        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                        userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(userCoordinates.coords.latitude, userCoordinates.coords.longitude);
                        document.getElementById('postErrandLatitudePosted').value = userCoordinates.coords.latitude;
                        document.getElementById('postErrandLongitudePosted').value = userCoordinates.coords.longitude;
                        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': userLatLng }, function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                var result = results[0];
                                locationPlaceholder = "";
                                for (var i = 0, len = result.address_components.length; i < len; i++) {
                                    var addressComponent = result.address_components[i];
                                    if (addressComponent.types.indexOf("locality") >= 0) locationPlaceholder = addressComponent.long_name;
                                }
                                if (locationPlaceholder != '') {
                                    document.getElementById('postErrandLocationPosted').value = locationPlaceholder;
                                    document.getElementById('postErrandLocationField').value = locationPlaceholder;
                                    window.alert(locationPlaceholder);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
            </script>
        <div id="postErrandErrandSection" class="manageSection">
            <p id="postErrandErrandSectionTitle" class="manageSectionTitle">
                errand
            </p>
            <div id="postErrandPictureArea" class="manageArea row">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Picture, new { @id = "postErrandPictureLabel", @class = "manageLabel col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-4" })
                <a id="postErrandPictureSelectionButton" class="manageField col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset0 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-6" href="#">
                    select a file...
                </a>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Picture, new { @id = "postErrandPictureField", @class = "manageField col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-6", @type = "file", @style = "display: none" })
            </div>
            <hr />
<!-- customization of picture selection button -->
            <script>
                jQuery("#postErrandPictureSelectionButton").click(function () {
                    $("#postErrandPictureField").click();
                    $("#postErrandCroppingArea").show();
                });
            </script>
            <script>
                $("#postErrandPictureField").change(function () {
                    var fullFileName = $("#postErrandPictureField").val()
                    $("#postErrandPictureSelectionButton").html(fullFileName.substr(fullFileName.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
                });
            </script>
            <div id="postErrandCroppingArea" class="manageArea row" style="display: none">
                <img id="postErrandOriginal" class="postErrandImage" src="" alt="" style="display: none" />
                <canvas id="postErrandCropped" class="postErrandImage" height="5" width="5"></canvas>
                <input id="postErrandButtonCrop" class="manageButton col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10" type="button" value="Crop" />
                <input id="postErrandCropX" class="postErrandData" name="postErrandCropX" type="hidden" />
                <input id="postErrandCropY" class="postErrandData" name="postErrandCropY" type="hidden" />
                <input id="postErrandCropW" class="postErrandData" name="postErrandCropW" type="hidden" />
                <input id="postErrandCropH" class="postErrandData" name="postErrandCropH" type="hidden" />
                <input id="postErrandCroppedPicture" class="postErrandData" name="postErrandCroppedPicture" type="hidden" />
            </div>
            <div id="postErrandLocationArea" class="manageArea row">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Location, new { @id = "postErrandLocationLabel", @class = "manageLabel col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-4" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Location, new { @id = "postErrandLocationField", @class = "manageField col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-6", @placeholder = "location" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Location, "", new { @id = "postErrandLocationValidation", @class = "manageValidation col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-4 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-6" })
            </div>
<!-- place autocomplete for Location -->
            <script>
                new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('postErrandLocationField')), { types: ['geocode'] });
            </script>
            <hr />
<!-- time autocomplete for StartDateTime -->
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function defaultStartDateTime() {
                    startDateTime = new Date();
                    var h = startDateTime.getHours() + 1;
                    if (h > 23) {
                        h = "00"
                    }
                    else {
                        if (h < 10) {
                            h = "0" + h
                        }
                    }
                    var d = startDateTime.getDate();
                    if (d < 10) {
                        d = "0" + d
                    }
                    var m = startDateTime.getMonth() + 1;
                    if (m < 10) {
                        m = "0" + m
                    }
                    var y = startDateTime.getFullYear();
                    placeholderStartDateTime = "";
                    placeholderStartDateTime = m + "/" + d + "/" + y + " " + h + ":00";
                    if (placeholderStartDateTime != '') {
                        document.getElementById('postErrandStartDateTimeField').value = placeholderStartDateTime;
                    };
                })
            </script>
            <div id="postErrandStartDateTimeArea" class="postErrandArea row">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDateTime, new { @id = "postErrandStartDateTimeLabel", @class = "manageLabel col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5" })
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ASAP, new { @id = "postErrandASAPLabel", @class = "manageLabel col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDateTime, new { @id = "postErrandStartDateTimeField", @class = "manageField col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-5 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-3", @onblur = "document.getElementById('postErrandEndDateTimeField').value = document.getElementById('postErrandStartDateTimeField').value;" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StartDateTime, new { @id = "postErrandStartDateTimeHiddenField", @class = "manageField col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-6" })
                <div id="postErrandASAPBuffer" class="postErrandBuffer col-xs-3 col-sm-5 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ASAP, new { @id = "postErrandASAPField", @class = "manageField col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1", @onclick = "document.getElementById('postErrandStartDateTimeHiddenField').value = placeholderStartDateTime; document.getElementById('postErrandStartDateTimeField').disabled=this.checked;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartDateTime, "", new { @id = "postErrandStartDateTimeValidation", @class = "manageValidation col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-5 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-3" })
            </div>
            <div id="postErrandEndDateTimeArea" class="postErrandArea row">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDateTime, new { @id = "postErrandEndDateTimeLabel", @class = "manageLabel col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5" })
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DurationInHours, new { @id = "postErrandDurationInHoursLabel", @class = "manageLabel col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDateTime, new { @id = "postErrandEndDateTimeField", @class = "manageField col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-5 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-3" })
                <div id="postErrandDurationInHoursBuffer" class="postErrandBuffer col-xs-1 col-sm-4 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DurationInHours, new { @id = "postErrandDurationInHoursField", @class = "manageField col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EndDateTime, "", new { @id = "postErrandEndDateTimeValidation", @class = "manageValidation col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-4 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-6" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DurationInHours, "", new { @id = "postErrandDurationInHoursValidation", @class = "manageValidation col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-4 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-6" })
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div id="postErrandOfferingArea" class="postErrandArea row">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Currency, new { @id = "postErrandCurrencyLabel", @class = "manageLabel col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 hidden-md hidden-lg" })
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Offering, new { @id = "postErrandOfferingLabel", @class = "manageLabel col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-3 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-4" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(Currencies => Currencies.Currency, new SelectList(ViewBag.currency as List<SelectListItem>, "Value", "Text"), "-select-", new { @id = "postErrandCurrencyField", @class = "manageField col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-0 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-2" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Offering, new { @id = "postErrandOfferingField", @class = "manageField col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-4", @placeholder = "$$$" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Currency, "", new { @id = "postErrandCurrencyValidation", @class = "manageValidation col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-4 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-6" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Offering, "", new { @id = "postErrandOfferingValidation", @class = "manageValidation col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-4 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-6" })
            </div>
            <div id="postErrandPriceArea" class="postErrandArea row">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.errandTax, new { @id = "postErrandTaxField", @class = "postErrandTaxField" })
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price, new { @id = "postErrandPriceLabel", @class = "manageLabel col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-4" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, new { @id = "postErrandPriceField", @class = "manageField col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-6", @disabled = true })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Price, new { @id = "postErrandPriceHiddenField", @class = "manageField col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-7 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-6" })
            </div>
<!-- calculate errand tax -->
            <script>
                document.getElementById('postErrandOfferingField').onchange = function () { calculateErrandTax() };
                function calculateErrandTax() {
                    var offering = document.getElementById('postErrandOfferingField').value;
                    var userRating = document.getElementById('postErrandUserRating').value;
                    var currency = document.getElementById('postErrandCurrencyField').value;
                    if (offering < 50) {
                        if (userRating > 5 * 0.95) {
                            var price = (offering * 1.12);
                            document.getElementById('postErrandTaxField').value = 0.12;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceHiddenField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                        }
                        else {
                            var price = offering * 1.15;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandTaxField').value = 0.15;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceHiddenField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (offering < 100) {
                        if (userRating > 5 * 0.95) {
                            var price = offering * 1.10;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandTaxField').value = 0.10;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceHiddenField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                        }
                        else {
                            var price = offering * 1.12;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandTaxField').value = 0.12;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceHiddenField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (offering < 500) {
                        if (userRating > 5 * 0.95) {
                            var price = offering * 1.07;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandTaxField').value = 0.07;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceHiddenField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                        }
                        else {
                            var price = offering * 1.10;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandTaxField').value = 0.10;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceHiddenField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (offering >= 500) {
                        if (userRating > 5 * 0.95) {
                            var price = offering * 1.05;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandTaxField').value = 0.05;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceHiddenField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                        }
                        else {
                            var price = offering * 1.07;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandTaxField').value = 0.07;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                            document.getElementById('postErrandPriceHiddenField').value = currency + " " + price.toFixed(2);
                        }
                    }
                };
            </script>
        </div>
            <div id="postErrandButtonSection" class="manageSection">
                <div id="postErrandButtonArea" class="manageArea row">
                    <button id="postErrandButton" class="manageButton col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10" type="submit">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </section>
    <div id="postErrandReturnToMenuSection" class="manageReturnToMenuSection">
        @Html.ActionLink("Return to Menu", "Index", "", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "postErrandReturnToMenuButton", @class = "manageReturnToMenuButton" })
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<!-- jCrop script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/master/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            if ($('#postErrandCroppingArea').width() > 500) {
                $('#postErrandPictureField').change(function () {
                    $('#postErrandOriginal').hide();
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#postErrandOriginal').show();
                        $('#postErrandOriginal').attr("src", e.target.result);
                        $('#postErrandOriginal').Jcrop({
                            onChange: SetCoordinates,
                            onSelect: SetCoordinates,
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            boxWidth: 450,
                            addClass: 'postErrandCropping'
                        });
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#postErrandPictureField').change(function () {
                    $('#postErrandOriginal').hide();
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#postErrandOriginal').show();
                        $('#postErrandOriginal').attr("src", e.target.result);
                        $('#postErrandOriginal').Jcrop({
                            onChange: SetCoordinates,
                            onSelect: SetCoordinates,
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            boxWidth: 250,
                            addClass: 'postErrandCropping'
                        });
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
                });
            }
            $('#postErrandButtonCrop').click(function () {
                var x1 = $('#postErrandCropX').val();
                var y1 = $('#postErrandCropY').val();
                var height = $('#postErrandCropH').val();
                var width = $('#postErrandCropW').val();
                var canvas = $("#postErrandCropped")[0];
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function () {
                    canvas.height = height;
                    canvas.width = width;
                    context.drawImage(img, x1, y1, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
                    var image = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
                    $('#postErrandCroppedPicture').val(image);
                    //$('#postErrandButtonUpload').show();
                    $('#postErrandCropped').hide();
                    $('#postErrandButtonCrop').hide();
                };
                img.src = $('#postErrandOriginal').attr("src");
            });
        });
        function SetCoordinates(c) {
            $('#postErrandCropX').val(c.x);
            $('#postErrandCropY').val(c.y);
            $('#postErrandCropW').val(c.w);
            $('#postErrandCropH').val(c.h);
            $('#postErrandButtonCrop').show();
        };
    </script>
<!-- pulling in Google Places library -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDQXVljq4LT-imCbZkOcC7_IiwcECEm0cc&libraries=places"></script>
<!-- pulling in DateTimePicker -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery('#postErrandStartDateTimeField').datetimepicker({
            format: 'm/d/Y H:i',
            step: '30',
            minDate: 0,
            defaultDate: 0,
            defaultTime: 0,
            yearStart: 2017,
            yearEnd: 2030,
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        jQuery('#postErrandEndDateTimeField').datetimepicker({
            format: 'm/d/Y H:i',
            step: '30',
            minDate: 0,
            defaultDate: 0,
            defaultTime: 0,
            yearStart: 2017,
            yearEnd: 2030,
        });
    </script>
}
```

The weird thing is also that it is not specific to an individual script, but rather affects all of them with the exception of jCrop, Google Places Lirbary and DateTimePicker (all of them are declared in my code).

Below is what I get from the console - but no clue what to do about it...

```
 SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
bootstrap.min.js (6,31)

 SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'concat' of undefined or null reference
jquery.mobile.min.js (4,5765)

 SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://jcrop-cdn.tapmodo.com/v2.0.0-RC1/js/Jcrop.js
localhost:44356 (1,1)

2 SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://jcrop-cdn.tapmodo.com/v2.0.0-RC1/css/Jcrop.css
localhost:44356 (1,1)

 SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
bootstrap.min.js (6,31)

 SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'concat' of undefined or null reference
jquery.mobile.min.js (4,5765)

 SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://jcrop-cdn.tapmodo.com/v2.0.0-RC1/js/Jcrop.js
PostErrand (1,1)

2 SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://jcrop-cdn.tapmodo.com/v2.0.0-RC1/css/Jcrop.css
PostErrand (1,1)

 SCRIPT1009: SCRIPT1009: Expected '}'
PostErrand (233,13)

 You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

14 SCRIPT5: SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

PostErrand (1,1)

5 SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

common.js (22,123)
```

Comment: Do you have any error in your browser console? Saying they "don't work" is not useful at all.

Comment: Nope - I am a newbie, so I would not even know how to get to an error there? It's simply not reacting/doing the job.

Comment: Press F12 and look in the console. There will almost certainly be something in there. Failing that, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: OK - added it in. Thx!

Comment: OK, that's a *lot* of errors. You now need to figure out what each one means - it's too much for a question here.

Comment: "Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery"...sounds like you included some bootstrap script before you included jQuery. The order you include the scripts is important, as some rely on others. Also it seems you included some of them twice (google maps warns you about this), you may have syntax errors in others and some are loaded over insecure HTTP. That's the summary of those errors. Work through them one by one. Since we mostly can't see how or where you load the scripts, it's hard to help. The rest of that wall of code you've shown is probably irrelevant, unless it also contains syntax errors

Comment: make sure you have included jquery in the first place

Answer (score 0):

OK - it's been a multitude of reasons, but you showing me how to get an understanding of what's going on already helped me a great deal, so thank you.

```
    <!-- autopopulate errand values with current location -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function defaultPostValues() {
            if (!navigator.geolocation) return;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (userCoordinates) {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(userCoordinates.coords.latitude, userCoordinates.coords.longitude);
                document.getElementById('postErrandLatitudePosted').value = userCoordinates.coords.latitude;
                document.getElementById('postErrandLongitudePosted').value = userCoordinates.coords.longitude;
                geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': userLatLng }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var result = results[0];
                        locationPlaceholder = "";
                        for (var i = 0, len = result.address_components.length; i < len; i++) {
                            var addressComponent = result.address_components[i];
                            if (addressComponent.types.indexOf("locality") >= 0) locationPlaceholder = addressComponent.long_name;
                        }
                        if (locationPlaceholder != '') {
                            document.getElementById('postErrandLocationPosted').value = locationPlaceholder;
                            document.getElementById('postErrandLocationField').value = locationPlaceholder;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Here I was simply missing the last

```
        });
    </script>
```